# MVC4 - When Passing Complex model to the Controller using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a Java Script function that is called when a user clicks add to basket, I am testing out my Ajax call before I put in all my logic to build the correct values form my form, (so hard coded for now.)

```
    function AddItem() {

    var myproduct = { Id: 1, Price: 17, ProductName:"product name" }

    var cartItem = { Quantity: 1, Product: myproduct };


    $.ajax({
        url: "/Cart/AddItem",
        type: 'post',
        data: cartItem,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.IsSuccess) {
                alert("test Hello Success");
            }

            alert("test HELLO Fail");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown + "- Error");
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is when testing this Java Script my strongly typed parameter inside my controller action only has some of the values set, 
My controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddItem(CartItem cartItem)
    {  
        cartItem.Cart = cartService.GetCartCurrent(this);
        cartService.SaveCartItem(cartItem);

       //bla bla bla

     }
```

The Cart Item definition looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class CartItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SelectedProductOption> SelectedProductOptions { get; set; }
    public virtual Cart Cart { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

So when I set a break-point CartItem.Quaintity = 1 but CartItem.Product is NOT NULL but the values for Product.Id = 0 and Product.Price is 0.

Why??

How do you set the inner object of the complex model.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to that your data is not being deserialized correctly. You can use `JavaScriptSerializer` to solve this.

Here

```
  var myproduct = { Id: 1, Price: 17, ProductName: "product name" };

            var cartItem = { Quantity: 1, Product: myproduct };


            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Index",
                type: 'post',
                data: "formData=" + JSON.stringify(cartItem),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.IsSuccess) {
                        alert("test Hello Success");
                    }

                    alert("test HELLO Fail");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown + "- Error");
                }
            });
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddItem(string formData)
    {  
        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        CartItem cartItem = js.Deserialize<CartItem>(formData);

        cartItem.Cart = cartService.GetCartCurrent(this);
        cartService.SaveCartItem(cartItem);

       //bla bla bla

     }
```

Comment: Nearly... Type 'AsoRock.Entities.Product' is not supported for deserialization of an array. any ideas?

Comment: It is probably happening because Product Class doesn't match the serialized object. Can you post your Product Object?
Also try using [Serializable] on product

Comment: Note: I just tested it myself and it is getting serialized.

Comment: [Serializable]
    public class Product
    {
        //[Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Well, I checked with simpler form of Product and it worked, so that must mean something else is screwing up.

Comment: Maybe I need to specify the category as well?

Comment: Nope, not specifying category shouldn't be a problem. Can you recheck your code if any of the property names are mismatching ? Also edit your question and post your product class there.

Comment: I think I got the problem. Are you by any chance using this ?

`var myproduct = { Id: 1, Price: 17, ProductName: "product name" };` ?
See product in you cartitem isn't an array so why should you pass it as an array ?

Comment: Or the second option is to change ` public virtual Product Product { get; set; }` to  `public virtual List<Product> Product { get; set; }`

Comment: That would be the problem.. I didn't realize I was passing an array for product I thought I was passing a single object how should it be?

Comment: Yes...Your Right... product is an arrary..!! Ahhhhhhhhh!

Comment: Thanks Pal.. It feels good to get help from a random person on the internet :-) Twitter..?? Follow me >>@mcDarke

Comment: And its a good... Question... You should really vote it up :-)

Comment: ok How do I populate Collections.. .Product works now.. but how do I populate the SelectedProductOptions its a collection do I map it to an array of JSON objects?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49341/discussion-between-user2537315-and-lokesh-suthar)